# OpenWebStart + IcedTea-Web: JNLP DOCTYPE or XSD

Tags: java, java-web-start, icedtea-web, openwebstart

What is the current JNLP specification (version) for [OpenWebStart](https://openwebstart.com/) (Java SE 11)?

There is an inofficial JNLP version list [here](https://www.mindprod.com/jgloss/jnlp.html#XSDSCHEMAS), but only up to Java SE 8.

Should still the DTD from Oracle/ Sun be used?

```
<!DOCTYPE jnlp PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc//DTD JNLP Descriptor 6.0//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/JNLP-6.0.dtd">
```

Or is there a newer version? Or even an official XSD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment OpenWebStart supports the definition / DTD. As far as I know there is only one difference: OpenWebStart supports a `vendor` attribute in the `j2se` tag. This attribute can be used to define a specific JDK/runtime vendor that should be used to start the application.